# How to align inner elements of a div, vertically with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align `div` inner elements vertically.

HTML

```
<div class="d1">
    <div class="d2"></div>
    <span>Hello how r u doing,</span>
    <span>Ismail?</span>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wgt8zg7t/

The output should be like:

`d2` at the top, and the `<span>` text should be below the `d2`:

```
d2
Hello how r u doing,
Ismail?
```

Note: I can't use position absolute to any of my `d1` inner elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `display` of `span tag` to `display:block` to get following output, as `default display` of `span` is `inline`. Where as `.d2` is a block element thus this align the elements one after another.

```
span{
  color:white;
  display:block;/*Add this*/
}
```

Comment: Okay that worked, But now There ls a little problem where if you add something like `span:hover{border-bottom:1px solid white;` the bottom border is 100% width to the parent element, have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/wgt8zg7t/3/ But I need it to be the size of the text itself

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply, The new Example you gave u r using an explicit width of the span width, which in my case the text comes up in random, Do I need to go up with any javascript code in order to follow it or is there any pure CSS which might help?

Comment: @Mr.Nobody Your question was regarding alignment of content which is working fine, now regarding on hover you want underline below text that should be of same width of text so can be done in 2 ways either set width for span and on hover use border-bottom or on hover use text-decoration as underline.

Answer (score 1):

Using `display:block` styling in the `<span>`element you can get your desired result.

Comment: position:block ? There is no such thing in CSS. position property has the value as absolute , fixed , relative, static , initial , inherit.

Comment: Sorry that would be display:block

Comment: Make an Edit Atleast!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `display:block` to your CSS

[Refer to this](https://jsfiddle.net/Ohmniox/wgt8zg7t/1/)

More information for display properties: [w3School: CSS Display property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Change  your css on the span. Add display block to it. See below.

```
span {
  color:white;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
span {
    color: white;
    display: block;  
}
```